# Бесконечная сборка библиотеки классов

Tags: c#, .net, dll, сборка, библиотека

Застопорился в разработке указанного в заголовке проекта из-за незаканчивающегося процесса построения проекта библиотеки классов. Синтаксических ошибок нет. В проекте есть взаимодействие с COM-компонентами, а также подключён NuGet-пакет DllExport версии 1.7.3. Ради эксперимента делал проект исполняемого файла, в который переносил "проблемный" код основного проекта, но всё собралось и заработало без нареканий.
В чём может быть проблема?

ЗЫ: версия студии - Community 2019 16.7.2; тип проекта - библиотека классов .Net Framework; целевая платформа - 4.5.
ЗЫ2: сам я не программист, если что.

Comment: Ну а в логах сборки есть что то?

Comment: Visual Studio со своими подсказами лезет под руку и может генерировать файлы .editorconfig, в которых переопределены настройки. Не уверен, что какая-либо настройка из этого файла может повлиять на сборку, но чем чёрт не шутит. Поищите такие файлы в вашем солюшене и, если вы не создавали их намеренно, удалите. А также файлы GlobalSuppressions.cs. Мало ли.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, помог даунгрейд NuGet-пакета DllExport до версии 1.7.1.

Добавлено: оказалось, что в настройках пакета можно включить использование адаптированного IL ассмеблера, который решает эту проблему (https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3246589/19872458/d05dd0d6-9fca-11e6-82a0-f5101974f06b.png).